# Magento UPS shipping don't work with Canada origin

Tags: ups

I am using UPS as shipping method,my issue is if I set my origin country as USA then it's showing me UPS shipping options in cart and checkout page. But if I set my origin country as Canada then it's not showing me any of the UPS shipping options.

I have set my Base currency, default Current and Allowed currency as Canadian Dollar, I have imported rates from manage currency also.

I Googled a lot but don't found any solution for this.

Is any one have faced such issue, or have solution for this? Please help.

Thank You

Comment: What is the service code you are using?

Comment: No service code I am using, I just enabled UPS with default settings

Comment: Did you come across this link https://developerkitcommunity.ups.com/index.php/Special:AWCforum/st/id45/Ship_To_Canada_(API).html

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem, but i resolved it.
You need to select the UPS type as United Postal Service XML and then put the Credentials Like User Id, Password and UPS account Name.

I think this info may not help you now but it will help others who'll face the same problem.